# What happens to questions submitted by deleted users?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-accounts

Consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824576/crystal-report), asked by a user (arpan) that is greyed out without a link to his user info.  I'm guessing the user was removed or is otherwise inactive.

What happens to questions submitted by those users?  If they are preserved, can moderators or other people accept answers?

Comment: That phenomenon also appears when a question is migrated from a site where the user had an account to a site where the user does not have an account.

Comment: If the question was migrated, I guess that can be accepted after the user creating an account?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins the account isn't automatically created when that happens?  Also, wouldn't there be a message saying that it was migrated?

Comment: @fedorqui - yes, that certainly can happen.

Comment: @Nirk - No - migration doesn't automatically create an account. And yes, there is a message.

Comment: That particular question might as well be deleted. There isn't enough information provided to answer it, and the asker hasn't been interested in it for about 4 years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What happens to questions submitted by those users?

The questions have the same fate as all other questions on the site - if they are good (and not duplicates), they will remain. If not, they will end up being closed and probably deleted.

> If they are preserved, can moderators or other people accept answers?

No. The right to accept an answer is reserved to the question original poster.